# How do I merge characters in a font like in Codepen.io?

Tags: fonts

Some fonts I've used tend to make "shortcut characters" like in Codepen.io one of my styles is a flamefox dark style, and it turns characters like == to a ＝ or /= to a ≠... or >= to a ≥ but only in a visual sense, if you hit backspace, it turns it back to a > as if you backspaced the =, so is there a way to make characters merge into words and symbols like this? its very interesting and I kinda require it for one of my projects, and is there a diffident term for this "character merging" in fonts? I tried multiple internet searches for things like character mixing and character merging in fonts, but couldn't find anything relative to what I mean.

Also I really want to be able to do this with truetype, I dont know if it requires specific font types though.

Comment: Oh yeah it also turns characters without unicode partners into special new characters, like === will turn into a triple-hyphen, which doesnt normally exist in unicode

Comment: These are called font ligatures.

Comment: thankyou for the information, I may be able to do a bit more research now

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer thanks to the comment by @gronostaj

> these are called font ligatures.

So I did some research and these can be created with most font programs to make "shortcut characters" some even allow you to turn 2 characters or more into full words or sentences.